# Android components in one row list

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am kind of new to Android and I wanted to make the UI design of my Android app which is simply a music player.

Logo, text, play image and duration are 4 components which I want to put in one row together.

When I try to put logo image, it doesn't show it.

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@drawable/white_selector"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/name"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/badges"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/badges"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/badges"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/badges"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    tools:text="Martin Garrix - Animals"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/badges"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/play"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
    android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/duration"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/asphalt"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:text="3:05"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update you XML as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:background="@drawable/white_selector"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/badges"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/play"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_play"
            android:contentDescription="@string/audio_play"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/duration"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            tools:text="3:05"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/logo"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/badges"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/badges"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        tools:text="Martin Garrix - Animals"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Ahmet? Do you know any way which i may use to separate eack row? İt could be a line or color. Any great theme or style?

Comment: Just use a view and give it a color and height=1dp

Answer (score 1):

The layout is a little messy, I think it can be refactored (the `LinearLayout` can be removed). Anyway, the only thing that seems wrong is the *name* `TextView` positioning, if it has `android:allignParentLeft` set to true it should not have `android:layout_toRightOf` set, and it also should be positioned to the left of the *logo* `ImageView`, not the *badges* `LinearLayout`, am I right?

The result should be something like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/logo"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/logo"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    tools:text="Martin Garrix - Animals"/>
```

Comment: Yes, the fact that the OP has `alignParentLeft="true"` on the TextView would explain why the logo image isn't showing up: it may be covered by the TextView.